# c# linq to sql - moving around FirstOrDefault() at end of linq breaks query

Tags: c#, .net, linq

What is the difference between the two pieces of code below?

This returns the data I expect....

```
return productTable.FirstOrDefault(p => p.ProductId == productId);
```

This doesn't....

```
return productTable.Where(x => x.ProductId == productId).FirstOrDefault();
```

I'm mainly just wondering if there's a logical difference between these two.

Comment: What do you mean when you say it doesn't work?

Comment: What is the data returned with the second one?  My guess is that the productID is different somewhere along the line...

Comment: A single 'Product' class is returned in the first query.  The second query, when passing the same id returns nothing.

Comment: Does the single `Product` instance returned have a `ProductId` that matches `productId`?

Comment: @Gabe good point.  Try viewing the second query w/o the FirstOrDefault.

Comment: If you set `context.Log = Console.Out;` does it show the same SQL for each query?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those queries should be essentially identical.  The parameterless version of `FirstOrDefault()` just grabs the first record available from the query, or default value (i.e., null) if no records are available.

**Edit 2** As duly pointed out in the comments, I should be using LINQ-to-SQL.  Here is a sample with LINQ-to-SQL:

```
using (ProductsDataContext context = new ProductsDataContext())
{
    context.Log = Console.Out;
    var p1 = context.Products.FirstOrDefault(p => p.ProductId == 1);
    var p2 = context.Products.Where(p => p.ProductId == 1).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Output (notice the queries are exactly identical):

> SELECT TOP (1) [t0].[ProductId],
>   [t0].[Name] FROM [dbo].[Products] AS
>   [t0] WHERE [t0].[ProductId] = @p0
>   -- @p0: Input Int (Size = -1; Prec = 0; Scale = 0) [1]
>   -- Context: SqlProvider(Sql2008) Model: AttributedMetaModel Build:
>   4.0.30319.1
>
> SELECT TOP (1) [t0].[ProductId],
>   [t0].[Name] FROM [dbo].[Products] AS
>   [t0] WHERE [t0].[ProductId] = @p0
>   -- @p0: Input Int (Size = -1; Prec = 0; Scale = 0) [1]
>   -- Context: SqlProvider(Sql2008) Model: AttributedMetaModel Build:
>   4.0.30319.1

**Edit**: Here is sample code to demonstrate they are the same thing:

```
class Product
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Product> productTable = new List<Product> {
            new Product { ProductId = 123, Name = "Cheese" },
            new Product { ProductId = 456, Name = "Milk" },
        };

        var r1 = productTable.FirstOrDefault(p => p.ProductId == 123);
        var r2 = productTable.Where(p => p.ProductId == 123).FirstOrDefault();

        // these print out the same thing
        Console.WriteLine(r1.Name);
        Console.WriteLine(r2.Name);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm using this with Linq 2 Sql and I think the issue lies there.  You're right, I tried a seperate test and they return the same data.  Must be something with my DataContext or some sort...

Comment: Is either instance of `productTable` a variable that has already had some LINQ-to-SQL logic applied to it, such as a filter clause of some sort?

Comment: you example is irrelevant as it is not using LINQ to SQL. We do not know how LINQ to SQL processes or compiles the expression tree represented by these two expressions. The best test would be to open up SQL Profiler and compare the queries generated. The point is, it's implementation dependant and you are testing against wrong implementation.

Comment: Thanks for all your help @mellamokb.  I'm marking as the answer since you answered what my original question was.

I opened up a new question in regard to what I slightly mentioned... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6026011/linq-2-sql-repository-isnt-working-when-not-wrapping-return-object-in-queryabl