# Linq 2 Sql - Repository isn't working unless query is done inside controller

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-sql, orm

I'm really struggling to understand an issue I'm facing.  I have a very simple repository with the following code:

```
public class ProductRepository : IProductRepository
{
    private Table<Product> productTable;

    public Product GetProductById(int id)
    {
         return productTable.Where(p => p.ProductId == id).Single();
    }

    public IQueryable<Product> GetProducts()
    {
        return productTable;
    }
 }
```

I have a controller called AddToCart().  The repository class above is passed into the controller via DI.  I pass a productId into this controller, and the repository method is called.  The problem is that a null value is returned when a Product does exist.

```
    public void AddToCart(int productId)
    {
        //Returns Null value
        Product product = productRepository.GetProductById(productId);
        ...
    }
```

I thought the issue may be that I need the `IQueryable<>` around the class that I'm returning.  I also modified my AddToCart method in various ways to try to get it to work.

```
public IQueryable<Product> GetProductById(int id)
{
    return productTable.Where(p => p.ProductId == id);
}

public void AddToCart(int productId)
{
    //Throws error / Returns Null value
    Product product = productRepository.GetProductById(productId).Single();
    //Returns Null value
    Product product = productRepository.GetProductById(productId).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

However, the following works and I have no reason why!  It's basically the same code, just being done in the controller.  Anyone have any ideas? :/

```
    public void AddToCart(int productId)
    {
        Product product = productRepository.GetProducts().FirstOrDefault(p => p.ProductId == productId);
    }
```

Comment: How / when is `productTable` created in `ProductRepository`?  How is the instance of `productRepository` created?

Comment: @contactmatt, what DI/IOC framework r u using? I believe that your problem is mostly related to that i.e. in one use case, the framework is injecting productTable correctly and in other case, it is not!

Comment: Is your Table being injected by Ninject? If so, can we see the binding?

Comment: I'll make the same comment here as I did on your other question: If you set `context.Log = Console.Out;` does it show the same SQL for each query?

Comment: @Gabe, I'll check.  I'm currently not in Visual Studio to test it, but where is the context.Log written?  To the visual studio console?

Comment: @Vinec Panuccio The table isn't being injected by ninject, the table contains a simple entity that's part of my domain.  The only injection is when injecting my repository to my controller

Comment: @contact: Using `Console.Out` sets the log to go to the command prompt window that you run the program from. If you don't have a command prompt window, you can just substitute a stream pointing to a text file.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to see what the problem is without more information.

1. How is GetProductById() returning null? Single() does not allow nulls to be returned and will throw an InvalidOperationException if there are no items or more than one item returned.
2. What is GetProducts() doing differently? Looking at your code, there should not be any problem.

What happens when you try this?

```
public class ProductRepository : IProductRepository
  {    
    private Table<Product> productTable;    

    public Product GetProductById(int id)    {         
        return GetProducts().Where(p => p.ProductId == id).Single();    
    }    

    public IQueryable<Product> GetProducts()    {        
      return productTable;    
    } 
}
```

As a side note, you should avoid using Single() if your are positive that only one item exists in your collection. Single will always itterate through your entire collection. First() is more efficient in that regard.

Comment: Wouldn't `GetProducts().Single(p => p.ProductId == id);` be more straightforward?

Comment: It's important that we find out what the problem is. My approach is really a band-aid solution that should tell us if that method is doing more than we can see.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if you may be having an issue with your Dependency Injection. You are using .Single() which, according to the docs, will throw an exception if there is not exactly one item in the collection that satisfies your condition.

I would try implementing this without using Dependency Injection and see if you get the same results. You can also try instantiating and returning a product item directly from the GetProductById method (instead of pulling from the database) to rule out anything weird happening with your DI.